# How to ensure (at compile time) that two macros are called in succession?

Tags: c++

I am currently working on a feature that raised a peculiarly difficult problem.

I have two macros :

```
#define FOO(A) do { /*...*/ } while(0)
#define FOO_END(A) do { /*...*/ } while(0)
```

What `FOO` actually does is that it tests values (in a very peculiar way), and `FOO_END` prints all the test results to the standard output. The detailed content is not publicated here because it's non-modifiable.

Each one of them have several inputs (not just "`A`"), but I limited it to one for simplicity.

These two macros are made to be used as this: several `FOO` macros are to be called in succession, then the `FOO_END` macro needs to be called at the end. I need to ensure that no "functionnal" code is called between the first and the last test (so the values all are coherent).

Example :

```
int main()
{
     // stuff...
     FOO(1);
     FOO(2);
     FOO_END(3);
     // stuff...
     FOO(4);
     FOO_END(5);
     // stuff...
     return 0;
}
```

Thus, the following code **must fail to compile** :

```
int main()
{
     FOO(1);
     bar(); // a random function
     FOO(2);
     FOO_END(3);
     return 0;
}
```

How can I redefine my macros in order to have this feature?

---

### Constraints

- The error must be seen at compile time. I already have a version that raises an error at runtime, but it's not enough for me.
- `FOO` and `FOO_END` *must* be macros. It's because I need to use
  `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` within them.
- C++11 is OK but I would prefer a C++03 solution. If it's possible of course.
- No external libraries, if possible. I have very low flexibility on the project I need it for. However, if no native solution is possible, I am still curious.

Comment: Best advice is not to write macros like that. Why do you need to use `__LINE__`?

Comment: Looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info): what are you _actually_  trying to achieve?

Comment: @Neil Butterworth : if the solution is not with macros it's OK, but I still need this feature. I need __LINE__ for tracing, but it must not be visible from the user of the macro (that's why I used a macro and not a function).

Comment: Can you add a FOO_START too? And are you ok with error messages that doesn't really make sense for the users? (e.g. various syntax errors). With a FOO_START, I think this could be hacked together... but it would be a hack.

Comment: The normal way to do tracing is to use TRACE macros, or your debugger.

Comment: It doesn't just trace things, but it's what I need __LINE__ for.

Comment: @Vultrao you should [edit]  your question and put all clarification _there_

Comment: @Vultrao and did you mean _atomically_  or _automatically_?

Comment: I would use a variadic function that accepts list of variables and/or conditions, that does evaluations and prints result at the end. Then there would be no way to put code in btw.

Comment: @Slava But also no way to use `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` as the OP seems to want to.

Comment: I really meant atomically -- in one single shot.

Comment: Macros are not called, but *expanded*. And macro-expansion is part of the preprocessing phase, inside your C or C++ compiler. BTW, you should provide some [MCVE]

Comment: What you want to do is unclear, and probably impossible. Did you consider *generating* some C++ code (perhaps with something like [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) or your own thing) ?

Comment: This has NO solution. A practical alternative is (1) place (expansion of) `FOO` in a class constructor and `END_FOO` in the destructor (2) create instance of that class with automatic storage duration wherever the usage of `FOO` is required.  This approach will (1) correctly match every usage of `FOO` with corresponding `END_FOO`  (2) work in any version of C++ (3) use no external libraries. No way to avoid matching `FOO` and `END_FOO`, so no need for a diagnostic if they don't match. Usage of `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` won't work as stipulated, but that's a rubbish requirement anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a start macro you can start an unfinished sentence in it

```
#define FOO_START uselessFOOFunction(
#define FOO ); do { /*...*/ } while(0); uselessFOOFunction(
#define FOO_END ); do { /*...*/ } while(0)

static void uselessFOOFunction(){}
```

So this will work :

```
int main()
{
     // stuff...
     FOO_START
     FOO
     FOO
     FOO_END;
     // stuff...
     FOO_START
     FOO
     FOO_END;
     // stuff...
     return 0;
}
```

And this will fail to compile :

```
int main()
{
     FOO_START
     FOO
     bar(); // a random function
     FOO
     FOO_END;
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: The downside of your solution is that you can't put semicolons at the end of the FOO statements. Do you think there is a better way to make the compiling error clearer to the user ?

Answer (score 1):

If you also add a FOO_START macro at the start, you could generate a code which will fail to compile with various errors for incorrect examples.
The downside is that the error message won't be about the use of the foo - it will be about the incorrect language constructs the macro expansions generate. You also won't be able to use local variables.
Because of this, I would say that in this form it is unusable, but maybe you could modify it to your use case - this is similar to how some unit test frameworks are implemented.

Here's a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

#define CONCAT(A,B) A ## B
#define ST_NAME(N)  CONCAT(ST_, N)
#define NP_NAME(N)  CONCAT(NP_, N)
#define np_NAME(N)  CONCAT(np_, N)
#define MEM_NAME(N)  CONCAT(mem_, N);
// NPs are helper structs that ensure that no data members are declared outside the FOO macros
#define NP_START struct NP_NAME(__LINE__) { int i;
#define NP_END } np_NAME(__LINE__); static_assert(sizeof(np_NAME(__LINE__)) == sizeof(int));

#define FOO_START struct { NP_START
#define FOO NP_END struct ST_NAME(__LINE__) { ST_NAME(__LINE__)() { std::cout << "hack!" << std::endl; } } MEM_NAME(__LINE__); NP_START
#define FOO_END NP_END } MEM_NAME(__LINE__);
void bar();

int main() {
  int i;
  FOO_START;
  FOO;
  i = 5; // error
  int j = bar(); // error
  FOO;
  bar(); // error
  FOO_END;

  return 0;
}
```

With this, you generate an anonymous local struct, and the code will be executed by its constructor.

Edit: fixed the issue mentioned by a comment. Static_assert requires C++11, or boost for 03.

Comment: Nice, this is pretty clever. Note that it's susceptible to things like `int x;` or (if using C++11) `int x = call_function();`.

Comment: Nice catch, fixed that too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it using the macros you've proposed. There's no way to ensure no code exists between your macro statements. You can change your approach, though.

Create a macro, `DO_FOO`, that takes a number `N` which is the number of times to do `FOO`. The `DO_FOO` automatically expands to `FOO` `N` times and a single `FOO_END`. Example:

```
#define DO_FOO_IMPL_1 FOO; FOO_END
#define DO_FOO_IMPL_2 FOO; DO_FOO_IMPL_1;
#define DO_FOO_IMPL_3 FOO; DO_FOO_IMPL_2;
#define DO_FOO_IMPL_4 FOO; DO_FOO_IMPL_3;
// ... and so on, up to some maximum number N
#define DO_FOO(N) DO_FOO_IMPL_ ## N
```

Then you use it like this:

```
int main()
{
     // stuff...
     DO_FOO(2);
     // stuff...
     DO_FOO(1);
     // stuff...
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: All my macros are actually taking several arguments. I just realized now that I forgot to mention it. But because of that you answer is not fit (but it's stil interesting). I'm gonna update my post.

Comment: @Vultrao: Stop moving the goal posts. So far you have claimed your macros take no parameters, 1 parameter, and several parameters. Which is it? *How many parameters does the macro take?* It matters. I'm voting to close your question as "unclear what you're asking" because it's not clear what you want.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be this:  if you don't want people calling arbitrary code between calls to FOO and FOO_END, then put all the FOO calls into a single FOO_LIST call which calls all of them and then calls FOO_END implicitly.  That way the rule is enforced by the macro syntax itself.

i.e. instead of:

```
FOO(1);
FOO(2);
FOO(3);
FOO_END;
```

have your program do this:

```
FOO_LIST(1, 2, 3);
```

... which will be expanded by the preprocessor to into `FOO(1); FOO(2); FOO(3); FOO_END();`

Here's an example implementation that supports up to 5 arguments in a FOO_LIST; it can be extended if you need more.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FOO(x)  do {printf("foo(%i)!\n", x);} while(0)
#define FOO_END do {printf("foo_end!\n\n");} while(0)

// Support up to 5 FOO calls in a FOO_LIST, for now (can be extended as necessary)
#define FOO_LIST_1(f1)                 {FOO(f1);                                     FOO_END;}
#define FOO_LIST_2(f1, f2)             {FOO(f1); FOO(f2);                            FOO_END;}
#define FOO_LIST_3(f1, f2, f3)         {FOO(f1); FOO(f2); FOO(f3);                   FOO_END;}
#define FOO_LIST_4(f1, f2, f3, f4)     {FOO(f1); FOO(f2); FOO(f3); FOO(f4);          FOO_END;}
#define FOO_LIST_5(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5) {FOO(f1); FOO(f2); FOO(f3); FOO(f4); FOO(f5); FOO_END;}

#define GET_MACRO(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,NAME,...) NAME
#define FOO_LIST(...) GET_MACRO(__VA_ARGS__, FOO_LIST_5, FOO_LIST_4, FOO_LIST_3, FOO_LIST_2, FOO_LIST_1)(__VA_ARGS__)

int main(int,char **)
{
   printf("Some functional code here...\n");
   FOO_LIST(1);

   printf("Some more functional code here...\n");
   FOO_LIST(1, 2);

   printf("Some more functional code here...\n");
   FOO_LIST(1, 2, 3);

   return 0;
}
```